# Pretrained CNN model for small images

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model, image-classification

I'm working on a project to classify the images from the fashion MNIST database. I'd like to use a pre-trained CNN (possibly one that I can fine-tune), but all the ones I find require image sizes of at least 224x224 pixels.

The images from the fashion MNIST database are 28x28x1 in size, and for this application I have 50000 training images and 20000 testing images. I tried simply resizing the 28x28 images to 224x224, but creating the array of size 20000x224x224 made Google Colab crash because it ran out of RAM...

I'm not sure if this is because I did something wrong or just because I have too many images to be resizing them to 224x224.

So, is there a model available for smaller images? I can't find anything for images smaller than 224x224. Or is there something else I could do here?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VGG19 with the input shape (32, 32, 3). (or VGG16)
32 is the least size you can input to VGG19.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf%20http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1556.pdf

And also, you should use **data_generator** to load the dataset.

Comment: What are VGC19 and VGC16?

Comment: @lowtex The model name is VGG16 and VGG19. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf%20http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.1556.pdf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).